# Sets of coprime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, additive-combinatorics

Consider the set $\{0, 3, 7, 15\}$ of four integers. If you add each of these numbers to a fixed power of 2, then the resulting four numbers are pairwise coprime. For example, $\{4, 7, 11, 19\}$ are pairwise coprime, as are  $\{32, 35, 39, 47\}$. I can construct similar sets of any finite size, and for any prime.

Is there a name for such sets or any literature about sets with this property? Thanks for any references!

Comment: Somewhat related are covering congruences, which are used to show certain expressions are never prime, such as 2^N + C.  Erdos and Pomerance have some articles.  You might also look up Guy's Unsolved Problems In Number Theory for similar problems.  Gerhard "Going Off On A Tangent" Paseman, 2014.11.29